# Odd problem with System.AccessViolationException

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, exception, access-violation

I have an asp.net (3.5) web application.
In one page i use an unmanaged C library (a simulator) that produces a set of results based on some input.

When i've set the `debug="false"` in web.config (Release mode) that call will result in a `System.AccessViolationException`. If i am in the debugger, or at least set `debug="true"` in web.config, that exception will **never** appear.

Because of the nature of the bug i placed the call inside a `try-catch` to log the exception and then the exception does not appear!

Is there some magical work on protected memory space when in debug mode and/or in a try-catch?

Comment: That is really weird.  Not that I am superstitious, but strange things have happened to me in the past.  That is why i stay away of the web programming stuff...  The AccessViolationException might be due to a disk access or other resource access that your application does not have permission to use.  It works when you are debugging perhaps because it has more permissions assigned to it during debugging. Maybe as the user, you are able to grant more permissions to the app, but an anonymous user does not have so many permissions, so it fails.

Comment: Do you know what line of code throws the exception? or does it just appear out of nowhere?  The latter is usually caused with Framework-related problems, and it usually happens during loading, at least for me.  Your simulator dll might not be in a folder with permissions, or maybe the simulator is trying to read/write without permissions during loading.

Comment: well i don't know the line of code inside the C application. It does in memory operations and uses a small file that exists inside the realm that the application has access to (App_Data). If it was only the debug mode problem i would consider it to be permission-related but the try-catch phenomenon makes me think that this is framework related

Comment: what are you doing in the catch block?  what is your authentication mode for the app?

Comment: the catch does nothing else but log the exception using log4net. I am using windows authentication

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AccessViolationException` in this context probably means your unmanaged C code is screwing up. It's overwriting the heap or something.

Keep in mind that many pieces of code were never written to be run in a multi-threaded environment like that of ASP.NET. They were never even tested in such an environment, or were only tested using some "desktop" form of multi-threading that does not apply to ASP.NET.

I had a problem like this once. A third-party DLL which claimed to be thread-safe was very *unsafe*. By attaching an unmanaged debugger to the ASP.NET worker process, it was possible to see that the application was writing all over the C runtime library heap, and the heap was complaining bitterly about it. And nothing was listening to the complaints.

It was necessary to wrap calls to this code in a `lock` block - to ensure that only one thread could call it at a time. This was sufficient to prevent all of the crashes, even under load.

This *still* might not suffice for all unmanaged code. A piece of code that assumes all calls will occur on the same thread, or that all calls from the same "session" occur on the same thread, will be disappointed, and may very well crash or do something worse. In that case, you might need to move that code into a separate Windows Service which only allows one single thread to access that library, *ever*.